# JSON jQuery no errors how to investigate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't see any error from console window, either I don't see that my code acted. How do I investigate and make my script fired correctly? Thanks

```
 var mylist  = [
{ title: 'a' },
{ title: 'b' },
{ title: 'c' },
{ title: 'd' },
{ title: 'e' },
{ title: 'f' },
{ title: 'g' },
{ title: 'h' },
{ title: 'i' },
{ title: 'j' },
{ title: 'k' },
{ title: 'l' },
{ title: 'm' },
{ title: 'n' },
{ title: 'o' },
{ title: 'p' },
{ title: 'q' }
];

$.getJSON(mylist, function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    console.log(items);
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in the console when you reach the console.log ?

Comment: *"how to investigate"* If something doesn't work, always read the **documentation** of the functions you are using, to make sure you are using them correctly: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what `$.getJSON` does. [As you can read the in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), the first argument must be a **URL**. `$.getJSON` then performs an Ajax request to the URL and parses the response as JSON.

You don't pass a URL and you don't even have JSON. All you have to do is iterate over the array:

```
var items = [];
$.each( mylist, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});

$( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bW8et/)

I don't know which output you want, but that should give you a start. Read the [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) documentation, and learn about how to [access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) [objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).